# Converting a factor to numeric without losing information R (as.numeric() doesn't seem to work)

Tags: r, r-factor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R - How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric in R without a loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/r-how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-in-r-without-a-loss-of-informat)

The following fact about the as.numeric() function has been brought to my attention

```
> blah<-c("4","8","10","15")
> blah
[1] "4"  "8"  "10" "15"
> blah.new<-as.factor(blah)
> blah.new
[1] 4  8  10 15
Levels: 10 15 4 8
> blah.new1<-as.numeric(blah.new)
> blah.new1
[1] 3 4 1 2
```

When I convert a factor with levels 4, 8, 10, and 15 to a quantitative variable using as.numeric(), every number is converted to a ranking, and the original values are lost.

How do I take the vector 'blah.new' that has levels 10,15, 4, and 8, and convert it to the numeric values 10, 15, 4, and 8?

(This issue has arisen because of a dataset where a quantitative variable is read by read.table() to be a factor)

Thank you!!!!

*****Update: FIGURED IT OUT******

```
blah.new1<-as.numeric(as.character(blah.new))
```

However, I am wondering where in documentation for as.numeric() does it say that this function converts arguments into a list of rankings?

Comment: This is documented in the section **Warning** of `?factor`

Comment: But it isn't in either of the R books I'm thumbing through and it sure threw me for a loop just now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, factor consists of indices and levels. This fact is very very important when you are struggling with factor.

For example,

```
> z <- factor(letters[c(3, 2, 3, 4)])

# human-friendly display, but internal structure is invisible
> z
[1] c b c d
Levels: b c d

# internal structure of factor
> unclass(z)
[1] 2 1 2 3
attr(,"levels")
[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

here, `z` has 4 elements. 
The **index** is `2, 1, 2, 3` in that order.
The **level** is associated with each **index**: 1 -> b, 2 -> c, 3 -> d.

Then, `as.numeric` converts simply the **index** part of factor into numeric.
`as.character` handles the index and levels, and generates character vector expressed by its **level**.

`?as.numeric` says that *Factors are handled by the default method*.