# What's wrong with as.numeric in R?

Tags: r

```
> X864291X8X74
[1] 8.0000000000  9.0000000000  10.0000000000 6.0000000000  8.0000000000 
10 Levels: 0.0000000000 10.0000000000 12.0000000000 3.0000000000 4.0000000000 6.0000000000 ... NULL

> as.numeric(X864291X8X74)

[1] 8 9 2 6 8
```

what did I misunterstood? shouldn't be the result of as.numeric 8 9 10 6 8?

How do I get the correct result?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with as.numeric in R.  It is working exactly as it should  ;)

Comment: Use `hablar::as_reliable_num` which converts the vector to numeric as you expect, i.e. to 8 9 10 6 8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your vector is a `factor`. This question has been asked quite a few times, ex: [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611810/converting-a-factor-to-numeric-without-losing-information-r-as-numeric-doesn), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798343/convert-factor-to-integer), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information). In order to convert a factor to numeric, you'll have to convert to `character` first. Try:

```
as.numeric(as.character(my_vec))
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at `?factor` states:

> To transform a factor `f` to approximately its original numeric values,
>   `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient
>   than `as.numeric(as.character(f)).`

So the following works as well:

```
as.numeric(levels(my_vec))[my_vec]
```