# Conversion String to double

Tags: r

After using the upper script, the Catcher4Test $ TimePlayed test converts 2250 to 2.25

Why?

Before script

[image: Before script]

After script

[image: After script]

thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Posting images of code is unhelpful as it means other users have to type your code out in order to help you. Please see [ask] to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R interprets '.' as a decimal place. When you convert a string to a numeric, you get this error. For example:

```
as.numeric('2.050')
[1] 2.05
```

To prevent this, do:

```
> as.numeric(str_remove(string = Catcher4Test$TimePlayed, pattern = '\\.'))
[1] 2250
```

Sidenote: Be careful, I would strongly suggest to rather use the below solution to be 100% sure that transformation of your character variables is correct:

```
> as.numeric(str_remove(string = as.character(Catcher4Test$TimePlayed), pattern = '\\.'))
[1] 2250
```

This is due to below problem:
[What's wrong with as.numeric in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013482/whats-wrong-with-as-numeric-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data uses "." to separate hundredths from thousandths. I would use `readr::parse_number` to tell R how to interpret your data. This is an example:

```
readr::parse_number("2.250", locale = locale(grouping_mark = "."))
```

I would suggest using one of the `readr` functions (`read_csv`, `read_tsv` etc.) to read in your data cleanly so you don't have to munge it after the fact.

```
readr::read_*("file", locale = locale(grouping_mark = "."))
```

There is a section on this in the excellent and free [R for Data Science resource](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html#numbers)