# R data frame all columns (factor) columns to decimal

Tags: r, sapply

Its simple question but looks like it doesn't exist in the stackoverflow

I have a data frame where all columns are factors I want to convert it to decimals.

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
2 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
3 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
4 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
5 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
6 0.76 0.84 0.76 0.73
```

I want to convert this without loosing the decimals.

```
df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

This doesn't retain the decimals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611810/converting-a-factor-to-numeric-without-losing-information-r-as-numeric-doesn

Comment: @Saurabh13 its converting single columns correct

Answer (score 2):

If they are truly factors, you need to go through another step:

The reason for `as.numeric` not working directly is because internally each factor is stored by its `levels` . you can access that through the `levels(factor_var)`. So when you apply `as.numeric` to a factor directly, what gets returned is their `levels`. 
Therefore, first make it a character, and then apply `as.numeric`

```
df <- sapply(df, as.character)
df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

Or you can nest them in a function:

```
convert_func<-function(x){  as.numeric(as.character(x))}
```

then :`df <- sapply(df, convert_func)`

I have never tried nesting them in the apply/lapply/sapply without a function, but it might work also.
or you can make a loop:

```
for (col in 1:ncol(df){ 
     df[col]<-as.numeric(as.character(df[col]))
     }
```

Comment: You can't directly nest them, but you can define an anonymous function like `sapply(df,  function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)) )`

Answer (score 2):

This should also work:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), as.numeric(x), x))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` to convert the `factor` columns to `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
   mutate_if(is.factor, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

---

With `base R`, we can do

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = "0.76", class = "factor"), 
Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.84", class = "factor"), 
Var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.76", class = "factor"), 
Var4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "0.73", class = "factor")),
 .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"), class = "data.frame")
```