# Does 0 plays any important role in as.numeric function when using factors in R

Tags: r

Hi guys :) I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611810/converting-a-factor-to-numeric-without-losing-information-r-as-numeric-doesn) for example but I would like to ask if 0 plays any important role using the as.numeric function. For example, we have the following simple code

```
x2<-factor(c(2,2,0,2), label=c('Male','Female'))
as.numeric(x2) #knonwing that this is not the appropriate command used , as.numeric(levels(x2))[x2] would be more appropriate but return NAs
```

this returns

```
[1] 2 2 1 2
```

Is 0 being replaced here by 1 ? Moreover,

```
unclass(x2)
```

seems to give the same thing as well:

```
[1] 2 2 1 2
attr(,"levels")
[1] "Male"   "Female"
```

It might be simple but I am trying to figure this out and it seems that I cant. Any help would be highly appreciated as I am new in R.

Comment: Factors in `R` are coded starting at 1, not 0. When you create the `factor` the value 0 is lost, unless it's a level, but in your case the levels are "Male" and "Female".

Comment: So how do you actually get back `c(2,2,0,2)` from there ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper ``factor`` is not an invertible transformation. Consider: 
``identical(factor(c(2,2,0,2), label=c('Male','Female')), factor(c(2,2,1,2), label=c('Male','Female')))``

Comment: I think this is the answer OP was looking for @orizon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` has no special meaning for `factor`.

As commenters have pointed out, `factor` recodes the input vector to an integer vector (starting with `1`) and slaps a name tag onto each integer (the levels).

In the most simplest case, `factor(c(2,2,0,2)`, the function takes the *unique* values of the input vector, sorts it, and converts it to a character vector, for the levels. I.e. the factor is internally represented as `c(2,2,1,2)` where `1` corresponds to `'0'` and `2` to `'2'`.

You then go further on by giving the levels some labels; these are normally identical to the levels. In your case `factor(c(2,2,0,2), labels=c('Male','Female'))`, the levels are still evaluated to the sorted, unique vector (i.e. `c(2,2,1,2)`) but the levels now have labels `Male` for *first* level and `Female` for *second* level.

We can decide which levels should be used, as in `factor(c(2,2,0,2), levels=c(2,0), labels=c('Male','Female'))`. Now we have been explicit towards which input value should have which level and label.